# How to plot phase planes of polar differential equations

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some phase planes with limit circles. I have the differential equations in polar form:

drdt = r(r^2 -1) dθdt = 1

is there a way to plot them from this using matplotlib? I was able to plot one that I have the original system form by using the original system like this:

```
xvalues, yvalues = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-2, 2, 0.1), np.arange(-2, 2, 0.1))
xdot = xvalues + yvalues - xvalues * (xvalues ** 2 + yvalues ** 2)
ydot = -xvalues + yvalues - yvalues * (xvalues ** 2 + yvalues ** 2)


plt.streamplot(xvalues, yvalues, xdot, ydot)
plt.grid(); 
plt.show()
```

this system is
dxdt = x + y - x(x^2 + y2)
dydt = -x + y - y(x^2 + y2)
and its polar form is:
drdt = r(1-r^2) dθdt = 1

But it would be tedious to covert them all to the original system, if its even possible. Appreciate any help I can get.

**Update**

So I came up with a method that comes close enough by solving the differential with scipy for a range of initial radii, and then plotting on X, Y with the conversion formula

```
    times = np.linspace(0, 10)
    r0s = np.arange(0, 3, 0.2)
    for r0 in r0s:
        z0 = [r0, r0] 
        solution = odeint(rmodel, z0, times)
        x = solution[:,0] * np.cos(solution[:,1])
        y = solution[:,0] * np.sin(solution[:,1])
        plt.plot(x, y)
```

This works well enough for now but I would really like a better solution.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, please add the solution as an answer, do not edit it into the question.

Comment: I posted it, however I was hoping someone had a better solution, which is why I simply edited it in.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a method that comes close enough by solving the differential with scipy for a range of initial radii, and then plotting on X, Y with the conversion formula

```
    times = np.linspace(0, 10)
    r0s = np.arange(0, 3, 0.2)
    for r0 in r0s:
        z0 = [r0, r0] 
        solution = odeint(rmodel, z0, times)
        x = solution[:,0] * np.cos(solution[:,1])
        y = solution[:,0] * np.sin(solution[:,1])
        plt.plot(x, y)
```

This works well enough for my purposes.

Comment: You can plot in polar co-ordinates directly using `plt.polar(theta, r)` I think.

Comment: Your `z0 = [r0, r0]` is bizarre, do you really want ` θ₀  ≡ r₀ ` ???